# GRANT PERMISSIONS ON SQL Server 2008,

Tags: sql-server, permissions, tsql, sql

I got the following issues while querying a database, and somehow I am not yet able to resolve it.

`1. The SELECT permission was denied on the object`

So I executed the following command on SSMS ( I am the `sa` )

`2. GRANT SELECT ON [PQR].[dbo].[XYZ]
to ABC`

I get the following error

`Cannot find the user 'ABC', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Can anyone please help?? I The user `ABC` does exist, I can see it under the database->security->users

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try this TSQL command, rather than your own:

```
USE [PQR]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[XYZ] to ABC
```